# Converting oracle.sql.timestamptz to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert the systimestamp of the (Oracle) database to a java.sql.Timestamp

(Part of) the code I have for testing the process is:

```
try {
    conn = this.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    stmt.execute("SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL");

    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();

    while(rs.next()) {
        TIMESTAMPTZ ts = (TIMESTAMPTZ) rs.getObject(1);
        System.out.println(ts);
        System.out.println(ts.getClass());
        System.out.println(ts.timestampValue());
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ@1e97f9f
class oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ

and then an exception:
java.sql.SQLException: Conversion to Timestamp failed
at oracle.sql.Datum.timestampValue(Datum.java:283)
at com.sumawest.test.model.UnitTest.testTimezone(UnitTest.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
at oracle.jdevimpl.junit.runner.TestRunner.doRun(TestRunner.java:111)
at oracle.jdevimpl.junit.runner.TestRunner.start(TestRunner.java:91)
at oracle.jdevimpl.junit.runner.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:43)
java.sql.SQLException: Conversion to Timestamp failed
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `to_char` function to convert it to a string and then use the value.

```
select to_char(systimestamp, 'IYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZD') as d from dual;
```

Comment: How does this answer helps converting to `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Answer (score 4):

If you decompile the code you can see that you are calling the `timestampValue` method of the parent `Datum` class.

This directly throws the exception *(no other code in the method)*. You need to call the `timestampValue` method of `TIMESTAMPTZ` itself passing a `Connection`.